# joining tables in view

Tags: t-sql, join

I am now concerned that I have not normalised the tables correctly as now I see no way to join them;

I have 1 table with 2 columns called Questions, and another table called answers with 10 columns, one for the userId then 9 columns which hold all the answers (int) for each user.

Everything is working well for inserts and updates, however I am having a heck of a time trying to create a view which will show all questions, each user and each of their responses to each question.

Question table;

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Questions](
[questionId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[question] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Questions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[questionId] ASC
 )WITH (
        PAD_INDEX  = OFF, 
        STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
        IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,       
        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
        ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON
       ) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer table;

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Answers](
[empID] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
[q1] [int] NULL,
[q2] [int] NULL,
[q3] [int] NULL,
[q4] [int] NULL,
[q5] [int] NULL,
[q6] [int] NULL,
[q7] [int] NULL,
[q8] [int] NULL,
[q9] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Answers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[empID] ASC
)WITH (
       PAD_INDEX  = OFF, 
       STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
       IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,   
       ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
       ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON
      ) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Nothing I have tried works, so any ideas from you all that can help me avoid re-doing the tables would be so greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance for any help.

Alex

Comment: Will you always only have 9 questions? Is the the answer to the question with `QuestionID = 1` stored in column `q1`?

Comment: Whether or not you *can* make this work, which I could imagine something on querying the system's columns for this table, ordering them, finding the appropriate column by its row number,turning the one you need into a string... The best answer here is to fix this. Your answer table should be `[employeeID] [questionID] [answer]`, if you want this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that your answer table should have a foreign key to the question table.  Unless an answer can refer to multiple questions, in which case I would say you should consider something like a mapping/relation table which has FKs to both answer and question tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to look into [pivot tables](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/05/22/sql-server-pivot-table-example/) to accomplish your task.

Comment: Hmm, after reading all the comments, I think you're right, that pivot tables are my answer - but I am still a bit confused by how to turn columns into rows. I have 20 sections of questions and I have a simple code routine to update and insert answers;

Comment: int i = 1; var q = new int[31]; var objDB01 = new dbconn(); const string strSQL = "insertInvestigationsResults";
objDB01.objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empId", logonName);
        foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
        { var rb = gvr.FindControl("investigate_list") as RadioButtonList; var quest = rb.SelectedValue;
            if (quest == "")
            {
                quest = "0";
            }
            int question = Convert.ToInt32(quest);
            objDB01.objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@q" + i, question);
            i++;
        }